# Back button, and list view not working in a service?

Tags: android, listview, service

I made a service to create a system overlay(button) that detects long presses here is my code:

```
public class myservice extends Service implements OnTouchListener {
WindowManager wm;
View myview;
LayoutInflater li;
Button b;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    System.out.println("\n=\n=\n=\n" + "oncreate service" + "\n=\n=\n=\n");

    li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            //WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_INPUT_METHOD |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            //WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    System.out.println("\n=\n=\n=\n" + "lp " + params + "\n=\n=\n=\n");

    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    myview = li.inflate(R.layout.test_layout, null);
    System.out.println("\n=\n=\n=\n" + "View inflated" + "\n=\n=\n=\n");

    System.out.println("\n=\n=\n=\n" + "Layout inflator = " + li + "\nWindow manager = " + wm + "\nparams = " + params + "\nView = " + myview + "\n=\n=\n=\n");


    myview.setOnTouchListener(this);
    System.out.println("\n=\n=\n=\n" + "On touch listener" + "\n=\n=\n=\n");

    wm.addView(myview, params);
    System.out.println("\n=\n=\n=\n" + "add view" + "\n=\n=\n=\n");


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    wm.removeView(myview);
    myview=null;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("\n=\n=\n=\n Inside On Touch method \n=\n=\n=\n");

    if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("\n=\n=\n=\ntouch " + event.getX() + " " + event.getY() + "\n=\n=\n=\n");
        return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

It is supposed to allow user to use the phone normally except for when the user presses the button. but i noticed that the back button is not working and the list views on my phone(like contacts, alarms, messages, whatsapp's list) are no more clickable. when i click the list item it shows the normal animation but nothing opens up.

I tried to find error and found that.

1. when i add TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, the problem remains.
2. when i add TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, and not use TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT problem is gone but now the button is not clickable, it's like a permanent image stuck without any use(not i want).

The icons are working absolutely fine its just back button and list view . WHy ? and how do i correct it ?

Comment: Why would you use a `Service` to interact directly with the UI?

Comment: can i have an activity that can detect a long press every time it happens ?

Comment: @Squonk i need to get long press, i cant use activity because it doesnt last(user may close it, and its not always on the top, pointless) and i am not able to use service because of this. now, is there a middle ground to all this or is there a way i can tackle this problem.

Comment: **"...is there a way i can tackle this problem."** I don't actually understand what your problem is. The user can be using very many apps on their device but you want to overlay something over that????

Comment: i need to make a button that is activated when longpressed which the user can access from anywhere on the phone i have been able to make such a button. but now the PROBLEM is that **the list views on the phone and the back button are not working properly**. i try to make a call by tapping on the name, and it doesnt click just shows animation of going back and up again same with alarms and whatsapp contacts.

Comment: +1 because, Yes, all the sample Overlay code looks the same, and breaks the BACK button (at least on 4.3 & 4.4)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` and not `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` (no longer receives clicks from 4.3)
2. Do not OR window types together - that is not how they work.

---

As you can see from my comment, I also used similar sample code from the many many posts here about how to do this. For some reason, the BACK button stopped working (on 2 devices).

Now it is working - sadly I don't know what the fix was:

- I changed the return of `onTouch()` from `false` to `true` and back again.
- I previously was assigning a title to the `params`, but I took that out.

But now I can't seem to break the button again, no matter what I do. Which is a pity - I would like to know how to disable the BACK button on a system-wide basis.

---

To me this suggests the old trick of doing a Clean & rebuild of your project. Or perhaps this is because we are using "hacks" to do the overlay thing.

BTW the lists are also working again. Sorry I can't be of more help.